# Is there any potential evidence that Grindelwald was an Obscurus?

Tags: harry-potter, gellert-grindelwald, obscurus

Was Grindelwald an Obscurus? In Fantastic Beasts, he has an obsession with them - especially Credence. It seems to me that a possible reason for that is that he was one himself (personal headcanon of mine.) So, in currently released canon, is there any potential evidence that he was in fact an Obscurus?

(I obviously don't mean canon that fully confirms he was or wasn't. That won't be possible until all the movies are released. I want canon that could be construed as evidence.)

Comment: I'm really confused at this...

Answer (score 5):

## Grindelwald probably wasn’t an Obscurial.

From all the evidence given, it’s most logical to conclude that Grindelwald is likely not an Obscurial.

### He didn’t have difficulty controlling his magic.

Obscurials tend to have an unstable use of magic. As a teenager when he met Dumbledore, Grindelwald seemed to have control over his magic enough to be Albus’s equal, as Aberforth described him.

> “And now a positively dangerous look crept over Aberforth’s face.
>
> ‘Grindelwald. And at last, my brother had an equal to talk to, someone just as bright and talented as he was.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 28 (The Missing Mirror)*</sup></sub>

Grindelwald is described as being precociously brilliant and having great abilities in magic, a description unlikely to apply to an Obscurial

> “Educated at Durmstrang, a school famous even then for its unfortunate tolerance of the Dark Arts, Grindelwald showed himself quite as precociously brilliant as Dumbledore. Rather than channel his abilities into the attainment of awards and prizes, however, Gellert Grindelwald devoted himself to other pursuits. At sixteen years old, even Durmstrang felt it could no longer turn a blind eye to the twisted experiments of Gellert Grindelwald, and he was expelled.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 18 (The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, Grindelwald attending Durmstrang proves he was born to a family with at least one wizard parent, since Durmstrang doesn’t admit Mudbloods. This makes him far less likely to be an Obscurial, as his parents would likely be glad to have a magical child and wouldn’t be a reason for him to repress his magic.

> “Well, you know his opinion of Dumbledore – the man’s such a Mudblood-lover – and Durmstrang doesn’t admit that sort of riff-raff.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 11 (Aboard the Hogwarts Express)*</sup></sub>

What’s known of Grindelwald’s youth seems to show that he’s a wizard in control of his power, not an Obscurial.

### He sought out an Obscurial externally.

Grindelwald sought after an Obscurial in New York, where he presumed it couldn’t be more than ten years old - which would be an illogical presumption if he knew that he was himself an Obscurial over ten years old.

> “**GRAVES**
>   
> My vision showed only the child’s immense power. He or she is no older than ten, and I saw this child in close proximity to your mother – she I saw so plainly.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Further evidence against Grindelwald being an Obscurial himself is his description of Credence as the only entity that can kill Dumbledore. Though he swore a blood pact with Dumbledore, it’d be strange for him to consider Credence the one “entity” capable if he had the same powers and is only hindered from killing Dumbledore himself by the existence of the blood pact.

> “**KRALL**
>   
> Albus Dumbledore.
>
> **GRINDELWALD**
>   
> If I asked you now to go to the school where he is hiding and kill him for me, would you do it for me, Krall?
>   
> *(smiles)*
>   Credence is the only entity alive . . . who can kill him.
>
> **KRALL**
>   
> You really think that he can kill the great—can kill Albus Dumbledore?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*</sup></sub>

Therefore, this likely means that Grindelwald needs Credence not only for his lack of blood pact but for Credence’s Obscurial abilities, which he doesn’t have himself.

Answer (score 3):

Nope... definitely not: one can only develop an obscurus when repressing his magic...

Here is the definition of obscurus from [the wiki](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Obscurus):

> An Obscurus is the manifestation of the repressed energy of a young wizard or witch (known as an Obscurial). Described as a "dark" and "parasitic" force, an Obscurus is created when the child in question **consciously attempts to repress their magical abilities** or **were forced to do so** through physical or psychological abuse. This energy can manifest itself as a separate entity that can erupt in violent, destructive fury.[1](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Obscurus)

Grindlewald was never shown to repress anything and uses magic excessively, even when he was young. He even duelled with Dumbledore, what would not have been possible, if he repressed his magic...

And for sure he would have never been a student at Durmstrang Institute...

And to nitpick a little: even if he had developed an obscurus, we would have never BEEEN one, at most he would have been an obscurial (as seen in above definition).

Answer (score -4):

Yes - There is possible evidence that Grindelwald was an Obscurus.

> "The argument became a fight. **Grindelwald lost control. That which I had always sensed in him, though I pretended not to, now sprang into terrible being.** And Ariana... after all my mother's care and caution... lay dead upon the floor." (Deathly Hallows - Kings Cross)

Although shaky, coupled with the evidence in the movies of his obsession with Credence, and in the books how he used to always hang around Ariana, leaves me to suspect that Grindelwald himself was an Obscurus - and that is the reason why he worked tirelessly to reveal the Wizarding World and to ensure no wizard had to suffer what he went through.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Dumbledore is referring to Grindelwald's prodigious (but thoroughly unmagical) rage

Comment: reading way too much into imo - Dumbledore is saying that he sensed your standard evil (might makes right, power over muggles, etc...all the stuff he has already talked about) and Grindlewald stopped putting a friendly face on things and revealed his true character. If Grindlewald was an Obscurus, he would have been shown to have been visibly / physically unstable, not just mentally unstable. Additionally, he probably wouldn't have lasted long being imprisoned until his old age